# Java игра. Угадай число

Tags: java

Коллеги, доброго дня. Не могу понять, как сделать правильно:
Необходимо сделать игру, в которой нужно угадать число компьютера.

Я специально задал условие диапазон от 1 до 2, чтобы было легче разобраться и выявить ошибки. Работает практически все, кроме того, что не проверяет введенную попытку по условию if (), else if()....

Если же я угадываю число, то он сразу выводит правильный ответ. Но почему, когда я ввожу число, предположим, меньше того, что он загадал, будет и дальше идти, пока не закончится число попыток, указанное в условие for (... i < 10 ...)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner gm = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Привет, друг! Я загадал число от 1 до 3, найдется ли силёнок угадать?: ");
        String word = gm.nextLine();
        switch (word) {
        case "Нет":
            System.out.print("Ну, что же, тогда заходи в другой раз!");
            break;

        case "Да":
            System.out.print("Да начнется игра, сынок! Какое число я загадал?: ");
            int count = gm.nextInt();
            int a = 1;
            int b = 2;
            int random_number = a + (int) (Math.random() * b);
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                if (random_number > count) {
                    System.out.println("Не верно:)! Мое число больше > твоего ");
                    System.out.print("Какое число я загадал?: ");
                    int number2 = gm.nextInt();


                } else if (random_number < count) {
                    System.out.println("Не верно:)! Мое число меньше < твоего ");
                    System.out.print("Какое число я загадал?: ");
                    int number3 = gm.nextInt();

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Урааа, ты угадал это число!: " + random_number);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Игра]

Comment: Вставьте код прямо в вопрос в виде текста, чтобы его могли скопировать и проверить. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью ссылки «править» под ним.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь:) Вставил.

Answer (score 4):

Как я понял, вы хотите дать 9 попыток угадывания. Окей. Но когда мы не угадываем, вы записываете новый вариант в локальную переменную `number`, а потом опять сверяете ваше загаданное число с `count`.

Вот только ваш `count`-то не изменился. Да и с чего же? Мы же создали какую-то никому не нужную `number`, которую даже не трогаем после создания, а не перезаписали `count`.

Ваша проблема решается записью новых вариантов в уже существующую переменную `count`, а не в новую `number`.

Так что просто меняйте все строчки

```
int number = ...
```

На

```
count = ...
```

И будет вам счастие!

Comment: Я бы с удовольствием вставил код, но число символом превышает допустимую норму (. 
А 10 попыток указано просто так, т.к. там всего навсего диапазон от 1 до 2. Т.е. указав 2, допустим, он напишет, что Мое число меньше. Указать 1, он так же напишет, что Мое число меньше, ходя по условию должно быть уже верно, т.к. если не 2 (из диапазона 1-2) то уже точно 1.

Comment: @НикитаТелегин Вы внимательнее-то прочитайте, что я написал) вы когда на второй попытке спрашиваете пользователя о числе, куда его записываете? Не в локальную ли переменную `number`? А теперь глазами по коду пробегитесь. Ничего странного? Она же не используется, блин. Так что меняйте `int number =` на `count =`. А код чтобы приложить, нужно нажать ctrl+k и просто его вставить в предложенное место.

Comment: Большое спасибо за разъяснения)!

Comment: @НикитаТелегин если это решило проблему, то клацните галку на ответе)

Comment: @Regent и действительно, пришло)

Answer (score 1):

У вас проверка идет по `count`. Если вы не угадали число, то вы присваиваете переменной `number` следующую попытку и не используете ее, при этом проверка все равно происходит по `count`.
Попробуйте сделать следующее:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { //10 попыток
    int count = gm.nextInt();
    if (count < randomNumber) { //в Java используется CamelCase
        //actions
    } else if (count > randomNumber) {
        //actions
    } else {
        //actions
        break;
    }
}
```

Теперь вы на каждой попытке будете задавать число в `count`, и оно будет использовано в условиях.

Comment: Большое спасибо:) !

Answer (score 0):

Переменные `number2` и `number3` нигде не используется:

```
int number2 = gm.nextInt();
//и забыли
```

Соответственно, все введенные числа, кроме первого, игнорируются. Проверяется каждый раз только первое введенное число:

```
if(random_number > count)
```

Решить проблему, можно каждый раз обновляя переменную `count`:

```
...
System.out.print("Какое число я загадал?: ");
count = gm.nextInt();
```

Заодно предложил бы дать ей более говорящее название, например `inputNumber`.

Переменные `number2` и `number3` можно убрать за ненадобностью.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!)

Comment: @НикитаТелегин Пожалуйста! Если проблема решена, то выберите ответ, который помог больше всего и [отметьте его как принятый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (слева от ответа должна быть серая галка)

Answer (score -1):

```
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int x=0; x<9; x++){
        int ran = (int)(Math.random()*10);
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches(Integer.toString(ran), in.nextLine()));
    }
```